# $f(x)\equiv 0\pmod p$ has a solution if and only if the Artin symbol $\sigma_p$ fix some root of $f$?

Tags: nt.number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Let $f(X)\in\mathbb{Z}[X]$ be a monic irreducible polynomial of degree $>1$, let $K$ be the splitting field of $f$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ with Galois group $G$. For a rational prime $p$  unramified in $K$, let $\sigma_p$ be the Artin symbol denoting the conjugacy class of $G$ consisting of the Frobenius automorphisms associated to primes above $p$.

I want to know that if the following statement is true ?

> $f(x)\equiv 0\pmod p$ has a solution if and only if $\sigma_p$ fix some root of $f$ ?

If all elements of $\sigma_p$ fix some root of $f$, say $\beta$. By the definition of the Frobenius automorphism, we see that $$\beta=\bigl(\frac{K/\mathbb{Q}}{\mathfrak{p_i}}\bigr)(\beta)\equiv \beta^p \pmod {\mathfrak{p}_i}$$
for every $\mathfrak{p}_i$ above $p$. Therefore $\bar{\beta}\in\mathcal{O}_K/\mathfrak{p}_i$ lies in $\mathbb{F}_p$ under the extension $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}\hookrightarrow \mathcal{O}_K/\mathfrak{p}_i$. Thus $f(\bar{\beta})=0$.

This seems to have shown the if part.

Conversely, if $f(x)\equiv 0\pmod p$ has a solution $\gamma\in \mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$, is it true that $\sigma_p$ fix some root of $f$ ?

edit: From the comment of Joachim König, if in addition that $p\nmid \Delta (f)$, i.e. $f$ mod $p$ is separable, then the converse is true.

Comment: The converse is only true up to finitely many primes (e.g., p could be ramified). It's true though in case f mod p is separable, since then the action of the Frobenius of the number field extension can be identified with action on the mod p roots.

Comment: @JoachimKönig Thanks a lot, I have edited the question. And I am trying to give a proof.

Comment: You need to demand more, for example $p$ being unramified *and* the root being a simple root. Otherwise there would still be counterexamples such as $f(x)=x^2+3$, where 2 is inert in spite of $f$ having a (double) root mod 2.

Comment: @JoachimKönig Yes, our settings now is that $p$ is unramified in $K$ and $f$ mod $p$ is separable.